# Git push doesn't upload the .git directory

Tags: git

I set up a remote directory on pythonanywhere and I pushed my code from my local repository. Everything is uploaded to the remote repo except the .git folder. So I can't use git on pythonanywhere and if I clone my code somewhere else I can't use git there either. What can I do so that git push uploads the .git directory? Thank you

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this? What is it you think you can actually gain by this? Both sides should have their own local .git dir and you shouldn't push it around.

Comment: I need to be able to clone the repository to an new computer and use git from this computer. I have my local git repo. I push it to the remote server. I clone it from the remote server to the new computer. How do I use git from the new computer?

Comment: How are you cloning in new computer?

Comment: git clone username@remoteserver.com:/dir/to/repo/my_repo.git

Comment: I'm running to the same problem! do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 7):

the .git folder contains local configurations and informations, so it's not on the remote server.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but there is likely a `.git` folder (or an equivalent) on the remote server. It is not synced indeed but there is one.

Comment: What I want to do is be able to git clone into another computer and then be able to use git (including git push) to that computer. Isn't this something common?

Answer (score 3):

The `.git` directory *is* the repository; the directory it lives in on your local machine is just the root directory of the tree object associated with the commit you checked out. You don't push `.git` because `push` already copies everything necessary from your local repo to the remote. When you clone a repository, everything necessary from the remote is copied into your local `.git` folder.

Comment: So if I want to use git form the computer I cloned to, I have to initialize an new git repo there?

Comment: No; `git clone` is essentially a short cut for 1) initializing a new repo; 2) making `origin` a remote for the repo you are cloning, 3) fetching from `origin`, and 4) checking out master. Once you've run `git clone`, your new repository is ready for use.

Comment: When I use git clone the code downloads to the local directory but there is no .git folder and I can't run any git commands. It's like it doesn't initialize a new repository in the local directory in which I clone to...

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` creates a new directory, which contains the working tree (All your code) and the git repo itself (in .git).

So `git clone remote:path/to/repo1` creates a directory: `repo1` which contains all your code and `repo1/.git`

Comment: That's my problem. The directory is created and all the code put inside but there is no .git folder.